# WebDeploy API (IIS 7) - "public API": resources?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, webdeploy

Does anyone know any resources for the WebDeploy API?  Has anyone used it?

I've tried asking on the official forum, and looked around the site (the one that says there's a 'Public API' but then has no links, articles, resources, blog posts or samples): http://forums.iis.net/t/1180561.aspx ..

There's a list of classes on MSDN, which as a resource is very poorly documented and useless - there's a single blog post with an app that uses it, but wraps the API (my point being, if it's a simple app, why wrap an API - is the API that bad?).  Le fin.

Should I just `Process.Start` on `msdeploy.exe` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any resources, Microsoft aren't interested in providing them, and they couldn't care less.

Comment: (I'm laughing at the obvious MS employee who didn't like this and downvoted, or person who has discovered an API created since I posted and didn't share a link..)